# Need to move PI to inside the root element

Tags: xslt

I have an xml file that starts with processing instruction at the top. So, I need to replace this PI`('?change' not '?xml')` to inside the root element. I mean below scenario is the original and look at the PI

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?change id="69817" type="addition" mark="start"?>
<part id="PARTIII">
    <title><p just="center" fli="0" li="0" ri="0" before="1" after="1">PART 3</p>
        <p fli="0" li="0" ri="0" just="center" before="0"><font size="normal" smallcaps="yes">Mergers and Acquisitions</font></p></title>
    <div class="annotations">
```

So, I need to move the first PI(change) that is before root element to inside the root element. How i can achieve this. Any help?

I mean the above code should be(look at the PI 'change')

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <part id="PARTIII"><?change id="69817" type="addition" mark="start"?>
        <title><p just="center" fli="0" li="0" ri="0" before="1" after="1">PART 3</p>
            <p fli="0" li="0" ri="0" just="center" before="0"><font size="normal" smallcaps="yes">Mergers and Acquisitions</font></p></title>
        <div class="annotations">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()[following-sibling::part]"/>

    <xsl:template match="part">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::processing-instruction()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```